# React setState doesn't update the state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-modal

I am currently using react-modal in my project and i have problem opening and closing it probably from other component.

```
class MainComponent {

   constructor() {
   this.state = {reportOpen: false};
   }

  closeReport = (e) => {
     this.setState({reportOpen: false}, () => 
console.log(this.state.reportOpen)); // This line print true !!!
  }

   render() {
      return (
         <Button onClick={(e) => this.setState({reportOpen: true})}/>
         <ReportModal isOpen={this.state.reportOpen} onClose= . 
{this.closeReport}/>
      )
   }
}



// Modal
   class ReportModal {
       static getDerivedStateFromProps(nextProps, prevState) {
        if (nextProps.isOpen !== prevState.isOpen) {
          return ({isOpen: nextProps.isOpen});
        }
        else {
          return null;
        }
      }

      render() {
         return <Modal isOpen={this.state.isOpen}
            onRequestClose={this.props.onClose}
            shouldCloseOnOverlayClick={true}
            shouldCloseOnEsc={true}/>
      }
    }
```

Due to the mentioned problem, I couldn't close the modal once i opened it. Please help me to figure out the problem here. Thanks for any help.

Comment: Could you please show us your real code and produce a [mcve] ?

Comment: Here's a minimal example based on your code which works as expected. https://codesandbox.io/s/5xzlrm61v4

Comment: @lh32 You have a dot after the onClose prop:
<ReportModal isOpen={this.state.reportOpen} onClose= . <-- HERE
{this.closeReport}/>

Answer (score 0):

1. Missing `extends React.Component` in class declaration.
2. Missing `super(props);` call in constructor.

Answer (score 0):

- Please debug at getDerivedStateFromProps for the new derived state.
- Also why don't you just handle the same in ReportModal component, the callback seems overwork